# How to make app in background like chat head of messenger in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to make app in background like  chat head of messenger when user but it in background and click on this bubble to open the app again .
I'm trying to use floaty_head package but it doesn't work .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you are referring to the Android Bubbles API [documented here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/bubbles). If that's the case, at the time of this writing I don't believe there are ready to use 3rd party packages on pub.dev that allow you to achieve this. Your best option at the moment is to write that code natively yourself and integrate it with your Flutter application using channels.

Comment: Thanks for your support , so kindly there is any documentation for ios ?

Comment: Unfortunately iOS does not support bubbles at all. The closest to what Bubbles API achieves for iOS is to use home-screen widgets using WidgetKit APIs documented here: https://developer.apple.com/widgets/